# Returning a task is complete in asyc method

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method that has to be async because it is calling an async method:

```
    public async Task TransitionToPendingApproval(Guid id)
    {
        // Update status to pending approval
        var cimp = Repository.GetById(id);
        ChangeCimpStatus(cimp, Dom.CimpStatus.PendingApproval);
        await EmailPendingApprovalAsync(cimp).ConfigureAwait(true);
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

I just want to return that the task has finished but I am getting this error:

```
Since 'CimpProvider.TransitionToPendingApproval(Guid)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'?
```

What am I doing wrong and how to I fix it?

Comment: Just return nothing in your case (remove last line completely).

Comment: OK, can you explain why?

Comment: When you mark method with "async", it's kind of wrapped in Task automatically, so it already (by default) returns Task. If it returns Task<T> - you need to provide that T (return something). If it returns just Task - that's analog of return void method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you return a `Task` instead of `Task< T>` you do not need to return anything. Just remove the last return statement completely.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674893.aspx for explanation.(Section 'Task Return Type')

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify "Task instead of Task".

Comment: sorry, it didn't include the generic part , updated my answer using a space

Comment: Yep, `await` can be the last statement in the method.